# How can i make MERGE call in java using HttpURLConnection or HttpClient library?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using web services of third party for my web application.
For updating an entity they providing MERGE method (POST method they are using for new entity(it requires all the fields)) so i have searched for this method is there any sample provide but no success.
Can somebody tell me how can i achieve this.
Can somebody also tell me how to use PATCH method as well??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `MERGE` and `PATCH` methods are not supported by `HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod`.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod-java.lang.String-) for `HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod`:

> Set the method for the URL request, one of: GET POST HEAD OPTIONS PUT DELETE TRACE are legal, subject to protocol restrictions. The default method is GET.

Is your third party web service an OData service? The `MERGE` method was invented for OData and doesn't exist in the official HTTP protocol. Here is the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-odata/59d5abd3-7b12-490a-a0e2-9d9324b91893) from Microsoft (the inventor of OData):

> The remainder of this section defines a custom HTTP MERGE method that is used in the OData 1.0 and OData 2.0 protocols to specify that an update is to be completed by using merge semantics... The only difference between an HTTP request that uses MERGE or PATCH and PUT is client intent... Since MERGE is not one of the verbs that is defined in the HTTP specification [RFC2616], using the MERGE verb might not flow through network intermediaries as seamlessly as methods that are defined in the HTTP specification...

As a solution, I would suggest sending your payload in an [OData batch request](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/batch-processing/). This is a special `POST` request whose payload can include multiple HTTP requests. You can specify your `MERGE` and `PATCH` requests inside the `batch` payload.